# How many bits are read by fgetc in a stream?

Tags: c

How many bits are read by the function fgetc in a stream?

The man page of fgetc tells that this function reads a "character", but a character is not a clear definition for me. How many bits does contain a "character" ? Is reading a character with fgetc equivalent as reading a byte?

Does it depend on the architecture of the machine and on the size of "char" or "byte"?

My objective is to read binary data in a stream with portability (byte=8bits or byte=16bits). Is it a better idea to use fread/fwrite with types like uintN_t instead of fgetc in order to control how many bits are read in the stream? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

> How many bits does contain a "character" ?

A character contains precisely `CHAR_BIT` bits, an implementation-specific value defined in `limits.h`.

```
/* Number of bits in a `char'.  */
#  define CHAR_BIT      8
```

> Is reading a character with fgetc equivalent as reading a byte

Yup, `fgetc` reads exactly one byte.

This portability problem isn't easily solvable. The best way around it is to not make assumptions on the binary representation.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to write binary data in a file shared between machines with different architecture I must pay attention to binary representation. I think using uintN_t solves this problem if you also pay attention to endianness.

Comment: @mvera If you need endianness independent output, you will need to either write a "BOM" (byte order mark, as for UTF-16 and UTF-32), or make sure each platform you want the software to run on has 8-bit bytes, which is every single popular platform that is in use on any significant scale today.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc` read exactly one *byte*. A character type (`signed char`, `char`, `unsigned char` and qualified versions) contains `CHAR_BIT` bits (`<limits.h>`), which is a constant greater than `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Your platform has a smallest unit of data, which corresponds to the C data type `char`. All I/O happens in units of `char`s. You are guaranteed that a char can hold the values 0–127, and either 0–255 or −127–127. Everything else is platform-specific. (The actual number of bits inside a `char` is contained in the macro `CHAR_BIT`.)

That said, as long as you only write and read values within the advertised range into each char, you are guaranteed that your program will work on any conforming platform. The only thing you are *not* guaranteed is that the resulting data stream will be binarily identical.

Comment: You're not guaranteed -128 for a signed `char`, only -127.

Comment: So I guess "character" means "char" in the man page of fgetc. So if I have a binary file containing 4 octets (32bits) that I want to interpret as 4 small int I must not use fgetc as depending on the architecture of the machine 8bits or 16bits, I will read respectively 2 chars or 4 chars before OEF. Is it true ?

Comment: You don't really have a "platform-independent" way of having 32 bits. Your platform, all the way down to your hardware, already delivers data in some sort of unit (i.e. bytes). You could not physically take a 4-byte stream of your 8bpB platform and read it on a 9bpB platform as is. If you send four bytes over the network, they'll be received as four bytes on the other end, but they take 32 bits on your machine and 36 on the other.

Comment: @david Why not -127 ? in limits.h we have : `#define SCHAR_MIN (-128)`

Comment: I agree with you. If you work on a single architecture you don't have to deal with bytes sizes. You have to if you work with different architectures.That's also true if you intend to make your files readable by other technologies such as Java or Pearl, you have to describe precisely the structure of your file bit per bit. I think that if everybody agrees that "character" means "char" I have the answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: You're right on the minimal minimum requirement (all of you); it's only -127. Fixed, and thanks! (Once more the cp***p***.com trap strikes.)